# In CoreData :+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am very new to Core Data and have been trying to following many tutorials, but most of them put all of the Core Data methods into AppDelegate.so any one help me please Thanks in advance

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    //    NSLog(@"Calling fetchedResultsController @ rootviewController");
    if (is_Searching && [search_string length])

    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate appdelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


        NSMutableArray * predicateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if (is_Searching && [search_string length]) {

            NSPredicate *predecate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayName CONTAINS [c] %@",search_string];
            [predicateArray addObject:predecate];

        }

        if ([[AppDelegate get_update_privacy_Array] count]) {

            for (NSString * jids in [AppDelegate get_update_privacy_Array]) {

                NSPredicate *predecate_blocked = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(nickname CONTAINS [c] %@ OR jidStr CONTAINS %@)" ,jids, jids];

                [predicateArray addObject:predecate_blocked];
            }
        }
        NSPredicate *predicate_final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                        predicateArray];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate_final];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        fetchedResultsController_search = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                              managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                                sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                                         cacheName:nil];
        [fetchedResultsController_search setDelegate:self];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![fetchedResultsController_search performFetch:&error])
        {
            //DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
        }
        if (![[fetchedResultsController_search fetchedObjects]count] && ![groupChatArray count]) {
        [AppDelegate alertWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No contact found!"];
        }
        return fetchedResultsController_search;

    }


    else
    {


        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate appdelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


        NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        if ([[AppDelegate get_update_privacy_Array] count]) {

            for (NSString * jids in [AppDelegate get_update_privacy_Array]) {

                NSPredicate *predecate_blocked = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(nickname CONTAINS [c] %@ OR jidStr CONTAINS %@)" ,jids, jids];

                [predicateArray addObject:predecate_blocked];
            }
        }
        NSPredicate *predicate_final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                        predicateArray];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate_final];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
        [fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
        {
            //DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
        }
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

}
```

XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject.m class

```
#import "XMPP.h"
#import "XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage.h"
#import "XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject.h"
#import "XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject.h"
#import "XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject.h"
#import "NSNumber+XMPP.h"

#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#warning This file must be compiled with ARC. Use -fobjc-arc flag (or convert project to ARC).
#endif


@interface XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) XMPPJID *primitiveJid;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *primitiveJidStr;

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *primitiveDisplayName;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger primitiveSection;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *primitiveSectionName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *primitiveSectionNum;

@end

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@implementation XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark Accessors
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


@dynamic jid, primitiveJid;
@dynamic jidStr, primitiveJidStr;
@dynamic streamBareJidStr;

@dynamic nickname;
@dynamic displayName, primitiveDisplayName;
@dynamic subscription;
@dynamic ask;
@dynamic unreadMessages;
@dynamic photo;

@dynamic section, primitiveSection;
@dynamic sectionName, primitiveSectionName;
@dynamic sectionNum, primitiveSectionNum;

@dynamic groups;
@dynamic primaryResource;
@dynamic resources;
@dynamic status;

- (XMPPJID *)jid
{
  // Create and cache the jid on demand

  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"jid"];
  XMPPJID *tmp = [self primitiveJid];
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"jid"];

  if (tmp == nil) {
    tmp = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[self jidStr]];

    [self setPrimitiveJid:tmp];
  }
  return tmp;
}

- (void)setJid:(XMPPJID *)jid
{
    self.jidStr = [jid bare];
}

- (void)setJidStr:(NSString *)jidStr
{  
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"jidStr"];
  [self setPrimitiveJidStr:jidStr];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"jidStr"];

  // If the jidStr changes, the jid becomes invalid.
  [self setPrimitiveJid:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)section
{
  // Create and cache the section on demand
  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"section"];
  NSInteger tmp = [self primitiveSection];
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"section"];

  // section uses zero, so to distinguish unset values, use NSNotFound
  if (tmp == NSNotFound) {
    tmp = [[self sectionNum] integerValue];

    [self setPrimitiveSection:tmp];
  }
  return tmp;
}

- (void)setSection:(NSInteger)value
{
    self.sectionNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:value];
}

- (NSInteger)primitiveSection
{
  return section;
}

- (void)setPrimitiveSection:(NSInteger)primitiveSection
{
  section = primitiveSection;
}



- (void)setSectionNum:(NSNumber *)sectionNum
{
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"sectionNum"];
  [self setPrimitiveSectionNum:sectionNum];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"sectionNum"];

  // If the sectionNum changes, the section becomes invalid.
  // section uses zero, so to distinguish unset values, use NSNotFound
  [self setPrimitiveSection:NSNotFound];
}

- (NSString *)sectionName
{
  // Create and cache the sectionName on demand

  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionName"];
  NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionName];
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionName"];

  if (tmp == nil) {
    // Section names are organized by capitalizing the first letter of the displayName

    NSString *upperCase = [self.displayName uppercaseString];

    // return the first character with support UTF-16:
    tmp = [upperCase substringWithRange:[upperCase rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0]];

    [self setPrimitiveSectionName:tmp];
  }
  return tmp;
}

- (void)setDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName
{  
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"displayName"];
  [self setPrimitiveDisplayName:displayName];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"displayName"];

  // If the displayName changes, the sectionName becomes invalid.
  [self setPrimitiveSectionName:nil];
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark NSManagedObject
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    // Section uses zero, so to distinguish unset values, use NSNotFound.

    self.primitiveSection = NSNotFound;
}

- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
    // Section uses zero, so to distinguish unset values, use NSNotFound.
    // 
    // Note: Do NOT use "self.section = NSNotFound" as this will in turn set the sectionNum.

    self.primitiveSection = NSNotFound;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark Creation & Updates
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

+ (id)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
                           withJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
                  streamBareJidStr:(NSString *)streamBareJidStr
{
    if (jid == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject: invalid jid (nil)");
        return nil;
    }

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *newUser;
    newUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                            inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    newUser.streamBareJidStr = streamBareJidStr;

    newUser.jid = jid;
    newUser.nickname = nil;

    newUser.displayName = [jid bare];

    return newUser;
}

+ (id)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
                          withItem:(NSXMLElement *)item
                  streamBareJidStr:(NSString *)streamBareJidStr
{
    NSString *jidStr = [item attributeStringValueForName:@"jid"];
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jidStr];

    if (jid == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject: invalid item (missing or invalid jid): %@", item);
        return nil;
    }

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *newUser;
    newUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                            inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    newUser.streamBareJidStr = streamBareJidStr;

    [newUser updateWithItem:item];

    return newUser;
}

- (void)updateGroupsWithItem:(NSXMLElement *)item
{
    XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject *group = nil;

    // clear existing group memberships first
    if ([self.groups count] > 0) {
        [self removeGroups:self.groups];
    }

    NSArray *groupItems = [item elementsForName:@"group"];
    NSString *groupName = nil;

    for (NSXMLElement *groupElement in groupItems) {
        groupName = [groupElement stringValue];

        group = [XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject fetchOrInsertGroupName:groupName 
                                                inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        if (group != nil) {
            [self addGroupsObject:group];
        }
    }
}

- (void)updateWithItem:(NSXMLElement *)item
{
    NSString *jidStr = [item attributeStringValueForName:@"jid"];
    XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jidStr];

    if (jid == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject: invalid item (missing or invalid jid): %@", item);
        return;
    }

    self.jid = jid;
    self.nickname = [item attributeStringValueForName:@"name"];

    self.displayName = (self.nickname != nil) ? self.nickname : jidStr;

    self.subscription = [item attributeStringValueForName:@"subscription"];
    self.ask = [item attributeStringValueForName:@"ask"];

    [self updateGroupsWithItem:item];
}

- (void)recalculatePrimaryResource
{
    self.primaryResource = nil;

    NSArray *sortedResources = [[self allResources] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    if ([sortedResources count] > 0)
    {
        XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *resource = [sortedResources objectAtIndex:0];

        // Primary resource must have a non-negative priority
        if ([resource priority] >= 0)
        {
            self.primaryResource = resource;

            if (resource.intShow >= 3)
                self.section = 0;
            else
                self.section = 1;
        }
    }

    if (self.primaryResource == nil)
    {
        self.section = 2;
    }
}

- (void)updateWithPresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence streamBareJidStr:(NSString *)streamBareJidStr
{
    XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *resource =
        (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *)[self resourceForJID:[presence from]];

    if ([[presence type] isEqualToString:@"unavailable"] || [presence isErrorPresence])
    {
        if (resource)
        {
            [self removeResourcesObject:resource];
            [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:resource];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (resource)
        {
            [resource updateWithPresence:presence];
        }
        else
        {
            XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *newResource;
            newResource = [XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject insertInManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]
                                                                       withPresence:presence
                                                                   streamBareJidStr:streamBareJidStr];

            [self addResourcesObject:newResource];
        }
    }

    [self recalculatePrimaryResource];
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark XMPPUser Protocol
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (BOOL)isOnline
{
    return (self.primaryResource != nil);
}

- (BOOL)isPendingApproval
{
    // Either of the following mean we're waiting to have our presence subscription approved:
    // <item ask='subscribe' subscription='none' jid='robbiehanson@deusty.com'/>
    // <item ask='subscribe' subscription='from' jid='robbiehanson@deusty.com'/>

    NSString *subscription = self.subscription;
    NSString *ask = self.ask;

    if ([subscription isEqualToString:@"none"] || [subscription isEqualToString:@"from"])
    {
        if ([ask isEqualToString:@"subscribe"])
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (id <XMPPResource>)resourceForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
{
    NSString *jidStr = [jid full];

    for (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *resource in [self resources])
    {
        if ([jidStr isEqualToString:[resource jidStr]])
        {
            return resource;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSArray *)allResources
{
    NSMutableArray *allResources = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject *resource in [[self resources] allObjects]) {

        if(![resource isDeleted])
        {
            [allResources addObject:resource];
        }
    }

    return allResources;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark Comparisons
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Returns the result of invoking compareByName:options: with no options.
**/
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByName:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)another
{
    return [self compareByName:another options:0];
}

/**
 * This method compares the two users according to their display name.
 * 
 * Options for the search — you can combine any of the following using a C bitwise OR operator:
 * NSCaseInsensitiveSearch, NSLiteralSearch, NSNumericSearch.
 * See "String Programming Guide for Cocoa" for details on these options.
**/
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByName:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)another options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
{
    NSString *myName = [self displayName];
    NSString *theirName = [another displayName];

    return [myName compare:theirName options:mask];
}

/**
 * Returns the result of invoking compareByAvailabilityName:options: with no options.
**/
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByAvailabilityName:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)another
{
    return [self compareByAvailabilityName:another options:0];
}

/**
 * This method compares the two users according to availability first, and then display name.
 * Thus available users come before unavailable users.
 * If both users are available, or both users are not available,
 * this method follows the same functionality as the compareByName:options: as documented above.
**/
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByAvailabilityName:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)another
                                        options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
{
    if ([self isOnline])
    {
        if ([another isOnline])
            return [self compareByName:another options:mask];
        else
            return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([another isOnline])
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else
            return [self compareByName:another options:mask];
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark KVO compliance methods
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingJid {
    // If the jidStr changes, the jid may change as well.
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"jidStr"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsOnline {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"primaryResource"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSection {
    // If the value of sectionNum changes, the section may change as well.
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"sectionNum"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionName {
    // If the value of displayName changes, the sectionName may change as well.
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"displayName"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingAllResources {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"resources"];
}

@end


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext_roster
{




    return [xmppRosterStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainThreadManagedObjectContext
{

    NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Context reserved for main thread only");

    if (mainThreadManagedObjectContext)
    {
        return mainThreadManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator)
    {
        XMPPLogVerbose(@"%@: Creating mainThreadManagedObjectContext", [self class]);

        if ([NSManagedObjectContext instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithConcurrencyType:)])
            mainThreadManagedObjectContext =
                [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        else
            mainThreadManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        mainThreadManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
        mainThreadManagedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        // Todo: If we knew that our private managedObjectContext was going to be the only one writing to the database,
        // then a small optimization would be to use it as the object when registering above.
    }

    return mainThreadManagedObjectContext;
}

- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *sender = (NSManagedObjectContext *)[notification object];

    if ((sender != mainThreadManagedObjectContext) &&
        (sender.persistentStoreCoordinator == mainThreadManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator))
    {
        XMPPLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - Merging changes into mainThreadManagedObjectContext", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [mainThreadManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
            [self mainThreadManagedObjectContextDidMergeChanges];
        });
    }
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    // This is a public method.
    // It may be invoked on any thread/queue.

    __block NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *result = nil;

    dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {

        if (persistentStoreCoordinator)
        {
            result = persistentStoreCoordinator;
            return;
        }

        NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
        if (mom == nil)
        {
            return;
        }

        XMPPLogVerbose(@"%@: Creating persistentStoreCoordinator", [self class]);

        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];

        if (databaseFileName)
        {
            // SQLite persistent store

            NSString *docsPath = [self persistentStoreDirectory];
            NSString *storePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseFileName];
            if (storePath)
            {
                // If storePath is nil, then NSURL will throw an exception

                if(autoRemovePreviousDatabaseFile)
                {
                    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:storePath])
                    {
                        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storePath error:nil];
                    }
                }

                [self willCreatePersistentStoreWithPath:storePath options:storeOptions];

                NSError *error = nil;

                BOOL didAddPersistentStore = [self addPersistentStoreWithPath:storePath options:storeOptions error:&error];

                if(autoRecreateDatabaseFile && !didAddPersistentStore)
                {
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storePath error:NULL];

                    didAddPersistentStore = [self addPersistentStoreWithPath:storePath options:storeOptions error:&error];
                }

                if (!didAddPersistentStore)
                {
                    [self didNotAddPersistentStoreWithPath:storePath options:storeOptions error:error];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                XMPPLogWarn(@"%@: Error creating persistentStoreCoordinator - Nil persistentStoreDirectory",
                            [self class]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // In-Memory persistent store

            [self willCreatePersistentStoreWithPath:nil options:storeOptions];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![self addPersistentStoreWithPath:nil options:storeOptions error:&error])
            {
                [self didNotAddPersistentStoreWithPath:nil options:storeOptions error:error];
            }
        }

        result = persistentStoreCoordinator;

    }};

    if (dispatch_get_specific(storageQueueTag))
        block();
    else
        dispatch_sync(storageQueue, block);

    return result;
}
```

error iam getting is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject''
```

Comment: can any one help me for this....

Comment: It looks like your AppDelegate code is returning a nil managed object context.  For more detail, post the code where managedObjectContext_roster is initialised

Comment: ok just check it i edited the question

Comment: Thanks.  When you run the app, do you see this message "Creating mainThreadManagedObjectContext" in the log?

Comment: No it wont show,just it will come like this +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject''

Comment: OK.  If you look in the AppDelegate code for creating the managedObjectContext, the "Creating Main Thread message" is displayed if the variable `coordinator` is not nil.  So in your case `coordinator` must be nil.  So, we now need to look at the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method, to understand why it is nil.  Can you post that code?

Comment: yh i have added just check it

Comment: OK - you need to debug that method with NSLog() and/or breakpoints.  There are several points which could be the problem, but I would check first whether the managedObjectModel (`mom`) is nil.

Comment: thxq if u find the answer let me know plz

Comment: I am facing this same error. @pbasdf . Pls help me..

Comment: @McDonal_11 I didn't get to the bottom of this problem.  Have you followed through the comments above?  The OP's problem lies somewhere in the `persistentStoreCoordinator` method, but your problem could be elsewhere.

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate appdelegate] managedObjectContext_roster]; Here I am getting NIL value in moc. That is my probs.  @pbasdf

Comment: @McDonal_11 Do you see either of these messages in the log: "Creating persistentStoreCoordinator" OR "Creating mainThreadManagedObjectContext" (or both)?

Comment: That is printing in log. In my coding,, Data base not creating. NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyChatModel.sqlite"];   This line is not workin.

Comment: @McDonal_11 Looks like your problem, and your code, is slightly different.  Can you post a separate question with the relevant bits of your code and the error?  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91914/discussion-between-mcdonal-11-and-pbasdf).

Comment: @pbasdf have you got any solution for this i am also facing same problem. If you resolved that issue can you help me