# XMPPFramework Swift fetch objects always null

Tags: swift, xmppframework

Hi i have a problem with xmppframework using swift, that i always get 0 element when fetch objects

```
func fetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController? {
    if fetchedResultsControllerVar == nil {

        let moc = managedObjectContext_roster() as NSManagedObjectContext?
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)

        let sd1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionNum", ascending: true)
        let sd2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayName", ascending: true)

        let sortDescriptors = [sd1, sd2]
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

        fetchRequest.entity = entity
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10

        fetchedResultsControllerVar = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionNum", cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsControllerVar?.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsControllerVar!.performFetch()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            abort()
        }
        //  if fetchedResultsControllerVar?.performFetch() == nil {
        //Handle fetch error
        //}
    }

    return fetchedResultsControllerVar!
}
```

I have activate in my setup using this code

```
xmppStreams = externalStream

    xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage()
    xmppRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage)

    xmppRoster!.autoFetchRoster = true;
    xmppRoster!.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true;

    xmppRoster!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    xmppRoster!.activate(xmppStreams)
```

But when i print in delegate functoin fetchedResultControllerVar.fetchedObjects it always return 0,but for jidList i can get my rosterlists.

```
func xmppRosterDidEndPopulating(sender: XMPPRoster?){
    var jidList = xmppRosterStorage!.jidsForXMPPStream(xmppStreams)
    fetchedResultsControllerVar!.fetchedObjects

    print("List=\(jidList)")

}
```

Did i miss something? am i must init XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject in my class? Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824377/in-coredata-entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter  Can any one guide me.. pls.. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are connected to `xmpp` before fetching your `roster`, even if you use `XMPPCoreData`.

I made a `Swift Wrapper` around the `XMPPFramework`, it will simplify the development of a basic chat app, and it will show you how to properly fetch your `roster`.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tarec I will update my answer, but this is a know issue and the real answer for it is to provide a complete code to better understand how to fetch the roster.

Comment: @Loegic I am facing the same error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824377/in-coredata-entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter  Can any one guide me.. pls.. how to solve this?

Comment: @McDonal_11 Download the sample project linked to my answer, it will help you

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. I am having sample proj. Its running succeccfully. When I am try to integrate with New Project file,, I am facing this error. Pls help me. @Loegic

Comment: @McDonal_11I want to help you, but you commented on 2 different error on SO, so I don't really know what is your problem buddy

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[AppDelegate appdelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];    Here I am getting NIL value in moc. That is my probs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91870/discussion-between-mcdonal-11-and-loegic).